# Can an XML doc without namespace be validated if the XSD defines a targetNamespace?

Tags: xml, namespaces, xml-namespaces, jaxb2, xsd-validation

A legacy app I'm rewriting now defines inbound XML messages for which there an XSD.

The schema looks like:

```
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="http://www.example.com/myapp">
  <xsd:element name="my-root">...</xsd:element>
```

The XML messages, however, do not contain an `xmlns` declaration. They start directly with `<my-root>`, not with `<myns:my-root xmlns:myns="http://www.example.com/myapp">`. Other than that, the structure is correct.

The new app will use JAXB2 (could use others, if needed, we use Spring O/X).

And now the question, which is the same as in the title: *are the circumstances or options in which the XML message without the namespace declaration still validate successfully against the schema?* I kind of doubt (I think it shouldn't, that's precisely why the schema defines a namespace), but nonetheless, is it possible ? If not, the easiest solution in my case is to remove the `targetNamespace` declaration from the XSD, it won't change and it will be obsoleted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your instance is not valid against the schema because it uses a different namespace.

It's almost valid, if as you say the namespace is the only difference; if you want to discount that difference, you will either have to change the instance before validation, or change the schema. Both can be done quite easily using XSLT; changing the instance is probably easier.